# How to mock when using Typeorm Transaction Decorator in NestJS application unit tests?

Tags: testing, nestjs, typeorm

```
@Transaction()
  async updateAndCreate(
    someEntity: SomeEntity,
    entityStatus: SOME_STATUS,
    someMsg: SOME_MESSAGE,
    additionalInfo: any,
    @TransactionManager() em?: EntityManager
  ) {
    someEntity.LastStatus = entityStatus
    await em. save(Invoice, invoice)
    return em. save(History, {
      someEntityId: someEntity.id,
      message: someMsg,
      status: entityStatus
      additionalInfo,
    })
  }
```

I am trying to create and use a method to use a series of transactions.

I tried to write a unit test for that method.
If @Transaction() is used, a Connection related error occurs.
If @TransactionManager() is used, an error occurs because the corresponding entity manager cannot be found.

Is there a way to test the success case without creating a memory DB and direct connection in that case?

Answer (score 4):

you can mock like this:

```
jest.mock('typeorm/decorator/transaction/Transaction', () => ({
  Transaction() {
    return jest.fn();
  },
}));
```